# Use regular expression to escape a special character " which is also used as delimiter

Tags: python, regex, string, text

" is used as a delimiter for each substring but also used as a special character inside each substring as /"

Is there an way to separate each substring based on the " delimiter with each substring containing \" if any.

**For example, String is:**

"we don't care about \"you\" " "I don't care \" \"about." "I care about you"

**Output:**

"we don't care about \"you\"

"I don't care \" \"about."

"I care about you"

**I tried:**

```
re.findall(r'(?:\"(.*?)\")', string)
```

but I am unable to escape through \".

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `\\"`?

Comment: found the answer: re.findall(r'"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"',b) where b is the string

Comment: Yeah, that did not solve the problem, I'll still see the substring being truncated at \" @JaredGoguen

Comment: I think you need to use negative lookbehind to do what you were trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way might be:

```
s = '"HI in \"blah\"" "seconds" "\"thi\"rd"'

s[1:-1].split('" "')
# ['HI in "blah"', 'seconds', '"thi"rd']
```

Comment: Perfect answer! It's easy and clean. Thanks a lot @Jared